# SQLalchemy/Flask - nested one to one

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use Flask+SQLAlchemy to create a procedural universe. Each System has planets, and each planet has cities etc. etc.

It all seems pretty straight forward (famous last words) but I'm getting the following error:

*' Traceback (most recent call last): line 75, in 
    print system.planets.cities
AttributeError: 'InstrumentedList' object has no attribute 'cities' '*

when I run the below:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import libtcodpy as libtcod
import random

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class System(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    planets = db.relationship('Planet', backref='system')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<System:{}>'.format(self.name)

class Planet(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    system_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('system.id'))
    cities = db.relationship('City', backref='planet')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Planet:{}>'.format(self.name)

class City(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    pop = db.Column(db.Integer)
    planet_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('planet.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<City:{}>'.format(self.name)

with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()

def init_systems():
    sysnum = random.randint(5,10)

    #init namegenerator
    libtcod.namegen_parse('data/systemnames.txt')

    while sysnum > 0:
        plannum = random.randint(3,8)
        sname = libtcod.namegen_generate('Systems')
        gensys = System(name=sname)
        gensys.planets = []
        while plannum > 0:
            pname = libtcod.namegen_generate('Planets')
            genplan = Planet(name=pname)
            genplan.cities = []
            citynum = random.randint(4,12)

            while citynum > 0:
                startpop = random.randint(10,1000)
                cname = libtcod.namegen_generate('Cities')
                gencit = City(name=cname, pop=startpop)
                genplan.cities.append(gencit)
                citynum -= 1

            gensys.planets.append(genplan)
            plannum -= 1

        db.session.add(gensys)
        db.session.commit()
        sysnum -= 1

init_systems()

system = System.query.first()
print system.name
print system.planets
print system.planets.cities
```

Any ideas? I know there are other ways of structuring things, but I'm looking to have a pretty straightforward model of straight inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not access the cities by calling `print system.planets.cities`. As system.planets is a list of planets you need to access the `cities` for each planet separately.

```
for planet in system.planets:
    print planet.cities
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I was looking at it completely the wrong way and this set me on the right track!